# perl DBI mysql bind variables in LIMIT clause

Tags: mysql, perl, data-binding

### In a perl-script: How can I bind a variable value to the limit-clause in a mysql-statement?

I am writing a perl-script, that reads some data from a mysql-table. Here is a shortened version of the original program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

#db-name, user-name and pw are hidden here.
#In the real programm this part works fine.
my $dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:database=***;host=localhost','***','***');

#in the real script $from and $amount are parameters 
#that are sent to this program from another source
my $from = 0;
my $amount = 5;

my $sql = 'SELECT `RefID` FROM `referenz` WHERE `RefID` > ? ORDER BY `RefID` ASC LIMIT 0,?;';
my $sthGetData = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sthGetData->execute($from,$amount);
while (my $ref = $sthGetData->fetchrow_hashref()) {
    if (defined($ref->{'RefID'})) {
        print $ref->{'RefID'}."\n";
    }
}
$dbh->disconnect();
exit(0);
```

The problem seems to be the `?`-sign in the `LIMIT`-clause of the sql-statement:

```
LIMIT 0,?
```

There is a similar `?`-phrase in the statement:

```
WHERE `RefID` > ?
```

But this is no problem. I've done this many times in other scripts. It works fine.

When I execute the script, I get this error:

```
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''5'' at line 1 at ./problem.pl line 17.
```

It looks, as if `$sthGetData->execute($from,$amount);` adds single-quotation-marks around each value that it binds to the statement, which results in

```
 LIMIT 0,'5'
```

instead of

```
 LIMIT 0,5
```

So, how can I avoid getting this error? How can I bind a variable value to the limit-clause in a mysql-statement?

```
Server-Typ: MySQL
Server Version: 5.6.19-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 - (Ubuntu)
```

Comment: I hope that's not your real database password in the `connect` statement...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arguments of the LIMIT are not expressions, so it can't take a placeholder.

> `LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}`

`LIMIT 0,?` is just as wrong as `LIMIT 0,4+4`

Comment: So what must I do to get a perl-Script, that reads a pre-defined number of rows?

Comment: `"SELECT ... LIMIT 0,$amount"`

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Be sure you sanitize your input when you interpolate variables in your SQL statements (you should be doing this anyway, but placeholders give you an extra layer of protection). [`LIMIT` *is* vulnerable to SQL injection](https://rateip.com/blog/sql-injections-in-mysql-limit-clause/).

Comment: After looking into this more, DBD::mysql *does* allow placeholders in the `LIMIT` clause. By default, all placeholders are quoted, causing the OP's problem, but this can be remedied by either 1) setting the type with `bind_param`, e.g. `$sth->bind_param(1, $limit, SQL_INTEGER);` or 2) turning on [`mysql_bind_type_guessing`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::mysql#mysql_bind_type_guessing). Either method would be safer than interpolating the variable into the SQL statement. I've voted to reopen, since DBD::CSV doesn't support these workarounds.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, DBD::mysql accepts them in the same sense that it accepts `?` as an entire SQL statement. It doesn't check if the `?` is used somewhere legitimate. You're recommending the exploitation of a bug. I would recommend *against* doing that, especially since you derive no benefit from doing so.

Comment: @ikegami I didn't realize you could pass an entire statement via a placeholder, but you're right. That seems...odd. While trying to see if that was actually exploitable, I managed to trigger a buffer overflow with: `my $sth = $dbh->prepare('?'); my $evil = 'delete from test where id > 0'; $sth->bind_param(1, $evil, SQL_INTEGER); $sth->execute;` (This was apparently [reported](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=61849) in 2010 but hasn't been fixed yet.)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, This is because it's not the MySQL handling the placeholders, but DBD::mysql, and it doesn't validate the SQL.